# Java source structure external to projects

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to structure a new Java code base and have an issue for which I need direction.

It had seemed sensible to have a repository with a single directory tree holding all the code consistent with the package name structure. I have several projects using this source and want these to use this code from the central repository. What I am finding is that netbeans is objecting to this. I can set my first project up fine, I add the top level src folder and include / exclude folders to identify the specific code for the project. The second project though causes netbeans to object saying the "Package folder already used in project".

My first question is whether I am trying to do something unconventional by having a single Java repository with several projects using different parts of the code.

Secondly how can I configure netbeans to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is too late...

Make a link to the original source in the second project.

This is what I have..

```
C:\dev\shared\src
C:\dev\ProjectOne\src (This includes the shared source just fine)
C:\dev\ProjectTwo\src (This one causes the warning when you add the shared src folder)
```

So, (on windows)
CD into `C:\dev\ProjectTwo\`
mklink /D sharedSrc `C:\dev\shared\src`

Result:

```
C:\dev\ProjectTwo\sharedSrc
```

Tell netbeans to reference the sharedSrc.

Answer (score 0):

When you create NetBeans project in one folder then NetBeans makes nbproject folder that contains all project's settings. You cannot do so NetBeans use another folders name. Therefore one folder can contain only one NetBeans project.

Of course you can open ‘projectui.properties’ file and to copy properties of required project (openProjectsDisplayNames.nn, openProjectsURLs.nn & openProjectsIcons.nn) but new project will use the same ‘nbproject’ folder. :-)
So, I see the next right way to use one source base.
- create new project's folder
- in this folder create NetBeans 'free form' project with custom source path
In case of maven project the solution is the same: separate folders with custom pom.xml.